# How to fit innerHtml into a p tag

Tags: css, angular

The problem is my innerHtml tag contains multiple HTML tag including img tag. Now my code is

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-light" style="max-height: 600px;">
            <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="editor">
                        <h3 class="fancyFont">Editor</h3>
                    </label>
                    <quill-editor [styles]="{height: '250px'}" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Preview</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-light p-4" style="background:lightgray;">
            <h3 class="fancyFont">Preview</h3>
            <p [innerHTML]="editorContent"></p>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to fit all the innerHtml in that p tag. Even though the styling of p tag is not applied on the innerHtml. and it is overflowing the p tag. I want to fix that. Attaching the picture for your reference.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should query in css the img tags under that container and set the width to 100%

```
p img
{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

And make sure that the p tag or the parent container have a defined width

Comment: i think it would be better to set `max-width: 100%` so that smaller images are not stretched

Comment: Damn ! on the save of the edit your comment appeared :D:D thanks ! i earned that +1 haha

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot. But irrespective of the tag I want to do it. Not only for an image.  can you help me out to do this @Kashkashio

Comment: you could set that same css to any element as long it has display block or inline-block and the parent has a defined width :)

if you still having troubles try to create a codepen or fiddle and i'l help you